# Simplify SRTP resolved on return type

Tags: f#

I have some production code that I'd like to simplify (especially in light of new SRTP F# behaviour).

The intention is to statically resolve a method/function based solely on the return type required.

A simplified version of it is this:

```
type TypeOf<'a> = T

type ZeroFactory = Z with
    static member Zero(_: ZeroFactory,_ : TypeOf<int>) : _ = 0
    static member Zero(_: ZeroFactory,_ : TypeOf<string>) : _ = ""
    
let inline inlineZero t = 
    ((^T or ^N) : (static member Zero : ^T * TypeOf< ^N > -> ^N) 
        (t, T))

let inline zero () = inlineZero Z

let foo : int = zero ()
let bar : string = zero ()
```

this code compiles and does what I intend, but has always felt overly contrived.

I CAN write this:

```
let inline inlineZero2 t = 
    (^T : (static member Zero : ^T * TypeOf< ^N > -> ^N) 
        (t, T))
```

and to my eyes, that would seem to be good enough, but if i write:

```
let inline zero2 () = inlineZero2 Z
```

I get

```
Error   FS0043  A unique overload for method 'Zero' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed.

Known return type: 'a

Known type parameters: < ZeroFactory , TypeOf<'a> >

Candidates:
 - static member ZeroFactory.Zero: ZeroFactory * TypeOf<int> -> int
 - static member ZeroFactory.Zero: ZeroFactory * TypeOf<string> ->
```

my hunch is that all the static type parameters in the method specification have to be mentioned on the left.

Comment: Doesn't the built-in [`LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-languageprimitives.html#GenericZero) solve essentially the same problem?

Comment: good point, looking though its looking for 'Zero' as a static member on the return type, im looking for Zero on some predetertimed typed. 2nd issue is that the F# code base makes me even more confused than i normally am.